# Insert an Image In a Word Document that Changes When Image File Changes

Tags: ms-word, insert, jpeg

I currently have a report being written in word. I have JPG files of graphs that are output from an Analysis. I would like to have the JPG image display in my word document but if I replace the file it would update the image in the word document.

Example: This image is in a folder named **graph.jpg** I would like to have this displayed in my word document report.

[image]

But later I may re run my analysis and overrite **graph.jpg** with the image below and I would like my word document to update reading that file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code for this. All you need to do is paste your image into the document with the 'paste link' option. That way, Word will the document whenever the image changes.